# Why did Astra transform the legends into particular objects?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In the new episode of *DC's Legends of Tomorrow* S06E05, Astra turns the legends into different objects using magic. These objects include a fork, a candlestick, a cheese slice, a flip phone, and a binder. I would like to know that why were these particular legends converted into these specific objects, is there any logic behind it or it was just a random thing?

Comment: They do all relate to the personalities of the characters.